# How to parse a fieldDecorator into a component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using [antd](https://ant.design/components/form/) to create a form and use a fieldDecorator to decorate the various form elements which gives me some extra functionality later. 
Everything works fine but I want to create the FormItems in separate files/components and have no idea how to parse this to a new component class.

Here is my code so far which works, but how would I extract and use the existing fieldDecorator in a separate component such as the ProcessSelect component for example.

```
class ZalosForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
      }
    })
  }
  render() {
    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
    const formItemLayout = {
      labelCol: { span: 6 },
      wrapperCol: { span: 14 }
    };
    return (
      <div>
        <Form inline style={{ marginTop: 10, marginBottom: 10 }} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <FormItem
            {...formItemLayout}
            hasFeedback
            >
            {getFieldDecorator('qualityLabel', {
              rules: [{
                min: 11, max: 11, message: 'Invalid QL'
              }]
            })(
              <Input style={{ width: '200px' }} size="default" placeholder="QL" />
              )}
          <FormItem>
            <ProcessSelect />
          </FormItem>
          <FormItem>
            <ButtonGroup size="default">
              <Button htmlType="submit" size="default" icon="search" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />
              <Button size="default" icon="close" />
            </ButtonGroup>
          </FormItem>
        </Form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: you can `export` from source file and `import` the same in the file you want